# Reading two bytes from array of bytes

Tags: java, byte

I am creating a simple aplication in Java, which allows me to read text file. I have a byte array which is wrapped into ByteBuffer:

```
 FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(name);
 FileChannel channel = inputStream.getChannel();
 byte[] bArray = new byte[8192];
 ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bArray);
 int read;
```

and then I use a while loop to go through the text file:

```
while ( (read=channel.read(byteBuffer)) != -1 )
{
    for ( int i=0; i<read; i++ )
        //my code
    byteBuffer.clear( );
}
```

My question is how to read a Unicode character in this case. Unicode characters consist of 2 bytes (16 bits) so I suppose that bArray[i] holds first (higher) 8 bits and the subsequent 8 bits is the second part of this character. So for instance if I need to find out whether this character: "#" is currently on index i and i + 1, can I do it like this?? ("#" in binary  representation: 0010 0011):

```
if (bArray[i] == (byte)10 && bArray[i+1] == (byte) 11)
```

Thanks for responds

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you want to read a text file at such a low level? Do you even know the encoding of the file you're reading?

Comment: If "#" is `0010 0011`, shouldn't you only be checking if `bArray[i] == 0x0` and `bArray[i+1] == 0x23`? Unicode is two bytes, and since "#" is part of the standard set of ASCII characters, it does not have any bits set in the higher byte, so its representation is `0000 0000 0010 0011`

Comment: @jonhopkins Actually, since java doesn't have a binary representation it really should be `0x0` and `0x23` respectively

Comment: @Jeff fair enough. I was just going off the provided example. I haven't worked with bytes in Java before

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is that you should not treat textual data as a stream of bytes. Specifically that means: **don't use `ByteBuffer`**.

Use an [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html), which knows how to interpret sequences of bytes using a given encoding.

Comment: +1.  If you want to read characters, use a `Reader` that knows which `Charset` to use to convert between bytes and characters.

Comment: The problem is that this reading of text file has to be very fast and if I read that file at such a low level, I can skip some characters and increase the efficiency...

Comment: @Husky have you benchmarked the code and found that an `InputStreamReader` is too slow? I seriously doubt it would be a bottleneck.

Comment: For Unicode variants: "UTF-8", "UTF-16LE", "UTF-16BE". Unicode numbers the characters well into the 3-byte range. UTF-8 is multibyte, UTF-16 2-byte, partially with incomplete characters.

Comment: Actually I found some benchmarks here: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly and that is the reason, why I am trying to do that in this way..

Comment: That's a 5-year-old benchmark. Much has changed in Java and JVM since then. I'm serious: do the simple, sensible thing first, _then_ measure (1) if your program is too slow and only then (2) if the biggest speedup will come from avoiding `InputStreamReader`. I don't see what this is if not premature optimization. If you need any encoding fancier than ASCII, 99%+ of the time, it simply does not make sense to roll your own implementation.